# Replace default Wordpress search behavior with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx, wordpress

I want to implement [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) in my Wordpress site but I'm not exactly sure how to change Wordpress search behavior to use Sphinx.

How do I get Sphinx Search engine to replace whatever Wordpress uses as default?  I also want to display search results in a div with animations and search options on a static front page with only the site logo above it.  If I use Sphinx, is there a way to use a Wordpress loop to return the search results with `query_posts` function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Searching the WordPress plugsin directory:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

seems sensible.